# How can i have a bar next to an axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

What i want:
[image: What i want]

I looked at the documentation examples but couldn't find anything similiar. Google searching for 'bar', 'bar next to axis', 'axis range' also did me no good.

Does anyone know if/how I can achieve what I drew so well in ms paint?
Using matplotlib

Comment: can you post some sample code of what has been attempted, current output and perhaps an image of the desired output

Comment: @etch_45 The image in the post is exactly the desired output, the red and green bar next to the y-axis. I have no code with which i attempted this yet becuase i don't know at what method to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this usually boils down to using matplotlib to "plot" the desired elements outside of the axes.  So rather than using `plot()` to draw lines in the axes, use it to draw things outside it's limits.  Key parameters are `clip_on=False` to allow things to show outside the axes, and `transform` to make it easier to specify you want to place things outside the axes.  There are [different options for `transform`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html); I use `ax.get_yaxis_transform()` so that you can still reference the y-axis range when determining how big to make the lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([1,2,3], [100, 500, 1000])
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_xlabel('x')

# outside the axes
x_pos = -0.095

ax.plot([x_pos, x_pos], # -0.095, units are width of the axes
        [0, 500], # 0 to 500, units are same as the y-axis
        clip_on=False,
        transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(),
        color='red')

ax.plot([x_pos, x_pos], [500, 700], clip_on=False, color='green',
        transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())
```

[image]

Getting the actual caps shown in your painting are a little trickier; there is an [`ax.errorbar()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html) which can be used, but the coordinates are entered a little differently (`x` and `y` have to be the point that is the middle of the intended bar, and `yerr` has to be distance from the middle.  This also annoyingly causes the x-axis to change (unlike `ax.plot()`), so you would need to add a call to `ax.set_xlim()`:

```
# added to above:
ax.errorbar(x=x_pos, y=900, yerr=100, transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(),
            clip_on=False, capsize=5, color='purple')
```

[image]

You can look into [`ax.annotate()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html) as well, but I haven't yet seen an example similar to what you want.

Comment: perfect, I'm going with the errorbar since i set an x and y limit anyway. Thanks!